# Using a bash variable to pass multiple headers to curl command

Tags: bash, curl

I would like to make `curl` request with multiple headers.The solution would be to make this command :

```
curl -H "keyheader: value" -H "2ndkeyheader: 2ndvalue" ...
```

My goal is to use only one variable with all the headers like :

```
headers='-H "keyheader: value" -H "2ndkeyheader: 2ndvalue" '
curl $headers
```

to send

```
curl -H "keyheader: value" -H "2ndkeyheader: 2ndvalue"
```

Currently, the problem is : I can use `'` or `"` to declare my string, but `bash` tries to run what's after `"-H"` as arguments and then answers :

```
command unknown
```

Would like to know what is going wrong here.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You just need to use an array and *not* a variable to pass the quoted strings.

```
declare -a curlArgs=('-H' "keyheader: value" '-H' "2ndkeyheader: 2ndvalue")
```

and now pass this array fully that way, the array expansion(with double-quotes) takes care of the arguments within double-quotes to be not split while passing.

```
curl "${curlArgs[@]}"
```

For more insight into why putting the args in your variables fail, see [BashFAQ/050 - I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050#I.27m_trying_to_put_a_command_in_a_variable.2C_but_the_complex_cases_always_fail.21)

Comment: Such a flex; nice way to use a Bash array.